# Non duplicate array value in c++

Tags: c++

I am writing a c++ program that takes input from user and enter that number in array. Furthermore i included that if a user enters number and it already exist in the list. Then console just display a message. But somehow when i enter a unique element it still show me

> Duplicate value not allowed

Kindly see this of code and tell me where i am wrong.

```
void addElement(int i){
    if (rear==-1 && top == 0){
        rear++;
        Array[rear]=i;
    }

    else {
            for(int l=1 ; l<=rear ; l++){
             if((Array[l]) == i){
                cout<<"\n*Duplicate value not allowed*\n";
             }
             else{
                 rear++;
                    Array[rear] = i;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should notice that when you check the duplicate, the element is inserted beforehand. So it definitely will tell you duplicate found.

Comment: @xhg thanks i got it..

Comment: Why don't you use a `std::set` instead?

Comment: that's because i don't know about it @ChristianHackl

Comment: @AhmadHabib: Well, now you do! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues I see with your logic,

1. in the for loop you are not iterating from the first element but the
   second element since the index is `1`
2. Once a duplicate is found you should exit from the for loop and if
   no duplicate was found then only insert the value, instead, you are
   doing it multiple times.

See the code below

```
void addElement(int i) {
    if (rear==-1 && top == 0) {
        rear++;
        Array[rear]=i;
    }

    else {
        for(int l=0 ; l<=rear ; l++) {
            if((Array[l]) == i){
                cout<<"\n*Duplicate value not allowed*\n";
                return;
            }     
        }
        rear++;
        Array[rear] = i;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i tried it with l = 0, it didn't worked either but i didn't tried returning when the duplicate is found.... it worked , thanks

Comment: BTW can i use "break" instead of return ?

Comment: Apart from that there is one more thing you should,see as suggested in the answer,

Comment: If you use break, then the statement after  for loop will also be executed but we don't want them to since, a duplicate was found

Comment: Thank you for the help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is flawed:

```
    for(int l=1 ; l<=rear ; l++){
        if((Array[l]) == i){
            cout<<"\n*Duplicate value not allowed*\n";
        } else {
            rear++;
            Array[rear] = i;
        }
    }
```

Here you check if the second element equals `i` (btw why dont you start with the first one at index 0 ?), if it isnt you add `i` to the array. Then you continue to check if the next element equals `i`. Thus, you will always first add `i` and then find that it is in the array.

Instead you should first check if it is in the array and only after you checked **all** the elements either add it or print the message.

Comment: i checked with the logic as ** l = 0** first it didn't worked either.
and the 'i' is element user entered which is checked with the previous elements of list.